# How to make a directory in site root a subdomain?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, subdomain, lamp

I have a `Ubuntu` `LAMP` site hosted at `vps.net`.

I have a directory called `john` that is accessible via `mysite.com/john` I would like it instead to be accessed via `john.mysite.com`

My site root is `/var/www` and this directory is at `/var/www/john`

What do I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: Clarifications, plz: 1) is it ok if both mysite.com/john and john.mysite.com work? 2) Should any subdirectory automatically be converted into a subdomain or only those you configure?

Comment: @Bittrance, I would prefer only john.domain work and not domain/john but its not a big deal either way. Also only for ones I configure, although I would also be interested in knowing how to make it auto for every directory.

Comment: Making new dirs become subdomains needs a script, AFAIK. Don't think you can express that in Apache config terms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a new site file at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/john.mysite.com`

Set up the site something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName john.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/john
    <Directory /var/www/john/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable the site with `a2ensite john.mysite.com`

Reload apache to enable the site: `service apache2 restart`

Comment: I tried this, - I replaced `mysite.com` with my actual site and I restarted apache differently: `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload` .. I didn't get any errors, but it doesn't seem to be working. Can I be missing something else? or does it take a while to work? Thanks.

Comment: @John: As mentioned in one of the other answers, you'll need to set up DNS to point to the site as well.  DNS will take some time, but the Apache part takes effect as soon as you restart the service.

Comment: Thanks, I just set the DNS, so I will wait a while and see if it works. :)

Comment: one last thing. `http` is pointing to `/var/www/john` but `https` is pointing to just `/var/www` any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @John You'll need to configure an SSL VirtualHost for the SSL listener, you can model it off of the `default-ssl` file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`.  Keep in mind that the certificate will throw a warning if it doesn't match the domain name.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from configuring Apache, don't forget also the DNS part: you will need a record for `john.mysite.com`, pointing to the same IP address `mysite.com` points to (if using an A record), or to `mysite.com` itself (if using a CNAME record).

Comment: Thanks, I did what Shane Madden suggested, I also just added the subdomain in the DNS manager at vps.net to point to the same IP like you said. It still isn't working, would it take a while before it starts to work?

Comment: Yes, public DNS always have some latency, when you make a modification it will need a while (usually 24-48 hours) to be acknowledged by the whole Internet. Meanwhile, if you want to test it, you can put an entry in the hosts file of any computer to map john.mysite.com to the server's IP address, and then test the URL in its browser.

Answer (score 3):

These steps worked for me in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x86_64:

You need to create a new site file at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/john.mysite.com.conf`

The extension `.conf` is very important, without it, the rest won't work!!

Then set up the site something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName john.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/john
    <Directory /var/www/john/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Save the changes and enable the site with the command:

```
sudo a2ensite john.mysite.com
```

Reload apache to enable the site with:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Restart apache service:

`sudo service apache2 restart`

After that, you need to set up DNS to point to the site as well (as a Subdomain), DNS will take some time but in my experience it only takes a few minutes (15).

Hope this helps!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a vhost for your webserver (assuming apache)
that has at least the following info

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName john.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/john
</VirtualHost>
```

this is not a definitive vhost file but is a starting point, it should go in the bottom of your httpd.conf file or wherever your system manages vhosts